# Are multiple domain can improve images loading speed

Tags: http, web-optimization

I read this article [Optimize Parallel Downloads to Minimize Object Overhead](http://www.websiteoptimization.com/speed/tweak/parallel/) and write a test demo
But the result is not I expected，look at the waterfall figure multiple domain's images indeed parallel download but the total time no less.

Who can tell me why,thanks

**multiple domain image download**

[image: multiple domain]

**single domain image download**

[image: single domain]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I think the problem with your test is that the network latency is so low (assuming its a local server), that your network performance isn't even playing a huge role here.  If you look at the time difference between those images it doesn't' even register in HTTPWatch. So the browser may be spending more time parsing, processing and rendering the downloads than it does actually downloading (just a guess).

I would hit this test site with something that will show off latency more.  If these sites are reachable on the internet, you can just use http://www.webpagetest.org/ and hit them from around the world...

~Sniff

P.S. Check out [Amdahl's law](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Amdahl%27s_law), it may have a little bearing here here ;-).